# C# How can I identify the method that created the thread the current method is in?

Tags: c#, multithreading, methods

I'm looking to identify the method that created the Thread that the current method is running in.

I would use new StackFrame(int).GetMethod().Name, but I'm in a new Thread at the time of running this, so this one is out.

An example of my code is below:

```cs
private void doSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(GenerateThreadMethod));
        thread.Start(new Dictionary<String, Object>() {
            { "date" , Convert.ToDateTime(monthCalendar.SelectionRange.Start)},
            { "path", myList[myListBox.SelectedIndex][1] }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}


private void GenerateThreadMethod(Object obj)
{
    Dictionary<String, Object> data = (Dictionary<String, Object>)obj;

    DateTime date = (DateTime)data["date"];
    String path = (String)data["path"];

    //I want to find the name of doSomething() right here

    doMoreThings(date, path);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no built in way to do this.  However you can pass an arbitrary object to your ParametrizedThreadStart delegate which can include whatever information you want to communicate including the calling method name.

Comment: While the other answers are great, I'm going to go with this one. I have also reconsidered my desire to pass information around at a "level" that is different from the code. I think this is the safest way for future development of the program.

Answer (score 2):

You can't identify the parent thread.

I've seen another suggest that you could try prefix the name of the new thread with the thread ID from the parent thread, and then create a constructor on the method you want to spawn that requires the thread ID from the parent.

You could then use this information to at least gain access to the parent thread, and go from there, but I'm not sure if that gets you close enough to what you were hoping to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to access it as your new thread has it's own context. I would rather suggest to pass the name of the caller when creating the thread.

So in the caller you would write

```
StackTrace st = new StackTrace ();
StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame (0);

MethodBase currentMethodName = sf.GetMethod ();
```

And pass the result to your new thread as parameter of the call.